# How to replace "Define name" manual input in formula

Tags: excel-formula, named-ranges, excel-indirect

I'm creating YTD summary based on particular month. Data is same format, sheets are named Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

Goal: summary sheet cell input "Feb" and needed data from Jan+Feb sheets is taken. If Dec, Jan+Feb+Mar+...+Dec data is summarized.

Partially solved with "Define name", where "Feb" is a `&named range&` list of Jan, Feb.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&named_range&"'!range"),criteria,INDIRECT("'"&named_range&"'!sum_range")))
```

In my file:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Feb&"'!A2:A3";TRUE);C4;INDIRECT("'"&Feb&"'!B2:B3")))
```

I tried to replace "Define name" "Feb" with formula linked to input period in cell `$H$1` with following code:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'&INDEX(H1;TRUE)&'!A2:A3";TRUE);C5;INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(H1;TRUE)&"'!B2:B3")))
```

It results in an error - My data range name "Feb" is not recognized

I don't know VBA. Please advise any formula or syntax correction

Comment: not sure why you use **SUMPRODUCT+SUMIF** as by the look of it you just try to SUMIF the same ranges across sheets based on certain criteria. I think you are over-complicating the structure of your workbook. I would suggest you to put the data of all months in one worksheet, and add a column next to the data to indicate which month they are from, and then on your YTD sheet just use a simple SUMIF to calculate the year-to-date figure. Using INDIRECT to fetch data across worksheet is quite complicated and will slow down the calculation.

Comment: On every sheet I have country information. Summary information "Turkey" to find and to sum Turkey sales on sheet Jan then on Feb, etc..

Comment: but still you can have all data on one sheet which will make this exercise much more straight forward.

Comment: thanks Terry, indeed a good idea to use simplier solution :)

Comment: I'm just afraid of another sheets data transfer - where some mistakes are possible.